# SVM() classifier training in python using cl.fit()

Tags: python, svm, feature-detection

I am making a program to train SVM (Support Vector Machine) classifier in python using the below code:
 `

```
print ("Fetching saved features and corresponding labels from disk")
features, labels = load_features_labels(1)
print("Features and labels successfully loaded")
print(np.array(labels))
print(len(np.array(features)))
print(len(np.array(labels)))
clf = LinearSVC()
print("Fitting classifier")
clf.fit(np.array(features), np.array(labels))
print("Classifier fitting completed")
print("Persisting classifier model")
pickle.dump(clf, open("clf.p", "wb"))
print("Model persistence completed")
```

but i am getting this output:

```
Fetching saved features and corresponding labels from disk
Features and labels successfully loaded
[1 1 1 ..., 0 0 0]
1722
1722
Fitting classifier
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 20, in <module>
    clf.fit(np.array(features), np.array(labels))
  File "/home/ws2/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/classes.py", line 205, in fit
    dtype=np.float64, order="C")
  File "/home/ws2/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 510, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
  File "/home/ws2/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 415, in check_array
    context))
ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(1722, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

As can be seen in the output that the total number of features and labels is equal i-e 1722. Why its showing this error:

```
ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(1722, 0)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your features array is not correct, it should have a form similar to this `np.array([[1,2,3],[2,2,2],[1,1,1]])`, more like an array of arrays. I'm suspecting you might have something like this `np.array([1,2,3,2,2,2,1,1,1])`?

Basically the `fit` method expects an array of n_samples and n_features, from the documentation "**fit(X,y) X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape = [n_samples, n_features]**". Your error message is telling you that no features have been provided and that's why I'm suspecting that instead of an array [n_samples,n_features] as the X parameter you are just feeding an array.

Comment: you could print `features.shape` to confirm my hypothesis, or maybe print the features, as you did with the labels, and show us how this variable looks like

Comment: I have solved the issue, I am basically applying HOG for feature extraction, cells_per_block = (5,5) was changed to (2,2), and this worked, but anyway, I have 1722 pictures on which I am training, shouldn't I also have 1722 features? is that right ?

Comment: In my understanding **features and samples are two different things**. If you have 1722 pictures you'll have 1722 samples, but it does not necessarily mean you'll extract 1722 features from it.

Comment: did a quick search to illustrate this, first image I found on a matrix of samples and their features, 'example1...exampleN' would be your pictures, size 1722, but the features found/extracted from them, the columns in the matrix, could be any value (http://images.slideplayer.com/24/7476331/slides/slide_7.jpg)